# Reduce Ubuntu Server size removing all packages excepting very basic ones (16.04 or 18.04)

Tags: 16.04, server, debian, software-uninstall

I would need a GNU/Linux better if based on the Debian family or even a slimed version of Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS if possible (what we have mirrored internally in my company, due to isolated cloud deployments), not requiring server features at all, to be honest.

Apart from the Kernel and related components, I would need only the very basic shell tools + option to install packages from our mirror.

I was trying to find some Debian or Ubuntu small versions, as DML (www.damnsmalllinux.org, unfortunately, discontinued), and I am still testing other options, but I definitively want to try to take an Ubuntu Server 16.04 as a base and remove all that is not necessary, but not sure from where to start...
I tried with the metapackages, but that is not working in the way as I expected...

Do someone know a way, or have an idea about how to do it, please?

Comment: You need to install Debian minimal installation. It only has basic apps. Other option is to install Ubuntu with minimal installation option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Yep, I didn't know that option in the usual installer. Anyway, a minimal install just with the openSSH server takes 1.2 GiB, bigger than Debian minimal install. SliTaz takes 140 MiB even with a GUI, but I cannot use such OS, not Debian based :(
I will you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely aware of the tools "debfoster" and "deborphan". With these, you can remove whatever you do not need in a rather easy way.

Once you have a set of packages you are happy for your servers to work with, you can set these as a set as described on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176134/installing-packages-by-importing-the-list-with-dpkg-set-selections

Comment: thank you very much, I will definitively try that.
Cheers